# How do I create a datetime object from day and time and handle the required timezone?

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I created a form with a DateField and a TimeField. When printing these from the routes.py I get these example values:

```
TimeField: 17:30:00
DateField: 2021-07-12
```

How can I turn those values into a datetime object, which I can submit to my Postgres Database? The required object format is DateTime. The Postgres Table is set up as TIMESTAMPTZ. I tried replace() to add the time to the DateField Data. But that does not work. I am new to datetimes and such, so please excuse my ignorance. How do the Timezones work? because I probably need to add the timezone somehow for the TIMESTAMPTZ, right?

Below is the minimal code for the functioning

forms.py

```
class CreateEvent(Form):
    dt = DateField('DateTimePicker')
    start_time = TimeField('Start')
    submit = SubmitField("Submit") 
models.py

class Events(db.Model):
    __tablename__='events'
    eid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    event_day = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    start_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    
    def __init__(self, event_day, start_time):
        self.event_day = event_day
        self.start_time = start_time
```

routes.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate() == False:
        return render_template('create.html', form=form)
    else:
        event_day = form.dt.data
        start_time = form.start_time.data
        print(start_time)
        print(event_day)
        start_time = event_day.replace(time=start_time)
        newevent = Events(event_day, start_time)
        db.session.add(newevent)
        db.session.commit()
        return "Success"
```

Just in case, here is the Postgres Create Statement for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    eid serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    event_day TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
    start_time TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: you can make it timestamp using this `"{} {}".format(DateField, TimeField)`. and then push it to your table

Answer (score 1):

pip install `dateutil`:

https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

then:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

TimeField = "17:30:00"
DateField = "2021-07-12"

parse(DateField + ' ' + TimeField)

datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 12, 17, 30)
```

You probably don't need to add a timezone, Postgres will use the `timezone` setting for the server. Postgres does not actually store the timezone in a timestamptz field. It just uses the `timezone` setting to rotate the value to a UTC time for storage.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but as an example, and you may have to install **pytz** from PIP (if not already present on your system). Python knows so-called **naive** datetime objects (that have no timezone context), and **time zone-aware** datetime objects.

So the goal is to build a string with the date and the time, then parse it into a datetime object. Next, we add the desired time zone (in this example it is assumed US/Pacific so change as appropriate).

```
import datetime
import pytz

TimeField = "17:30:00"
DateField = "2021-07-12"

current_tz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')

# parse string into naive datetime object
dt_naive = datetime.datetime.strptime(f"{DateField} {TimeField}", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# convert to time zone-aware datetime
dt_aware = current_tz.localize(dt_naive)
```